# scyllaDB scala driver phantom store method throwing exception/error

Tags: scala, scylla

i am following this [guide](https://university.scylladb.com/courses/using-scylla-drivers/lessons/coding-with-scala-part-1/) and using the same code but in `sbt 1.2.8` the code for store method is giving an error message

```
 case class Mutant(
                   firstName: String,
                   lastName: String,
                   address: String,
                   pictureLocation: String

             )


   abstract class Mutants extends Table[Mutants,Mutant] {
      override def tableName: String = "mutant_data"
    
      object firstName extends StringColumn with PartitionKey {
        override def name = "first_name"
      }
    
      object lastName extends StringColumn with PartitionKey {
        override def name = "last_name"
      }
    
      object adress extends StringColumn
    
      object pictureLocation extends StringColumn {
        override def name = "picture_location"
      }
    
    }

`class MutantsDatabase(override val connector: CassandraConnection) extends` Database[MutantsDatabase](connector) {
          object mutants extends Mutants with Connector
        }
      

class MutantInsert {

        val connection: CassandraConnection =
            ContactPoints(List("scylla-node1:9042", "scylla-node2:9042", "scylla-node3:9042"))
              .keySpace("catalog")
    
    val db = new MutantsDatabase(connection)
    import db.{session, space}
    
        val insertionResult:Future[ResultSet] = db.mutants.store(mu).future()
    
    }
```

when i compile the code i got the error message

```
value future is not a member of com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.InsertQuery.Default[db.cql.Mutants,models.Mutant]
```

when i add this import statement

```
import com.outworkers.phantom.dsl._
```

the error goes away but i got a run time exception on the same store method line

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation to com.outworkers.phantom.ResultSet
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest is to get the actual app from
https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-code-samples/tree/master/mms/scala

you can see how this should be done so it compiles and runs to avoid implicit scala overrides

hth
L